TypeError: Many2many fields res.partner.supplier.channel_ids and res.partner.channel_ids use the same table and columns
I am developing a simple module for Odoo 18.
I have created the following Model (like shown in docs):
class Supplier(models.Model):
    _name = "res.partner.supplier"
    _inherit = "res.partner"

It gives the following error:
TypeError: Many2many fields res.partner.supplier.channel_ids and res.partner.channel_ids use the same table and columns

I have searched stackoverflow for answers and found similar issues:

odoo15 - TypeError: Many2many fields library.book.partner.channel_ids and res.partner.channel_ids use the same table and columns
odoo16 - "Many2many fields" error occurs when inheriting the model in Odoo

I tried to implement suggested logic, but it doesn't work.
This code:
class Supplier(models.Model):
    _name = "res.partner.supplier"
    _inherit = "res.partner"
    
    channel_ids = fields.Many2many(
        comodel_name='mail.channel',  # The target model
        relation='mail_channel_res_partner_supplier',  # The name of the relation table
        column1='res_partner_supplier_id',  # The column for cps.supplier
        column2='channel_id',  # The column for mail.channel
        string="Channels"
    )

I get these warning and error:
WARNING db_101 odoo.fields: Field res.partner.supplier.channel_ids with unknown comodel_name 'mail.channel'

ERROR db_101 odoo.sql_db: bad query: b'ALTER TABLE "mail_message_res_partner_starred_rel" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("res_partner_supplier_id") REFERENCES "res_partner_supplier"("id") ON DELETE cascade'
ERROR: column "res_partner_supplier_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "res_partner_supplier_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

So, it seems that there is no 'mail.channel' any more.
Any help please?

This question is similar to: TypeError: Many2many fields library.book.partner.channel_ids and res.partner.channel_ids use the same table and columns. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Next time i will read the question more carefully. It's obviously no duplicate. Do you have module "mail" in your module's manifest as dependency?

Oh and which odoo version do your work on?

error msg says all: <<unknown comodel_name 'mail.channel'>> ...so correct the comodel if it is already existing, or create it

That model is from module mail. It's written correcty, that's why i mentioned a missing dependency.

@CZoellner I have mail installed. It is Odoo 18. Odoo 18 has changes compare to other version.

Having the module installed is not necessarily enough. In such cases, it is always important to maintain the dependencies in your module correctly.

@CZoellner I have it dependencies. Maybe this issue related to the odoo 18 code changes?

Please change the relational table name, as it already exists
relation='mail_channel_res_partner_supplier2'
